# How to get back incorrect NER predictions in sklearn-crfsuite

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, named-entity-recognition, crf

I am performing NER using sklearn-crfsuite. I am trying to report back on an entity mention by entity mention case as a true positive (both prediction and expected correct even if no entity), false positive (prediction says yes, expected no) or false negative (prediction says no, expected yes).

I cannot see how to get anything other than tag/token based summary statistics for NER performance.

I would be OK with a different way of grouping entity mentions such as: correct, incorrect, partial, missing, spurious.  I can write a whole bunch of code around it myself to try to accomplish this (and might have to), but there has to be a single call to get this info?

Here are some of the calls that are being made to get the summary statistics:

```
from sklearn import metrics
report = metrics.classification_report(targets, predictions,
                                       output_dict=output_dict)
precision = metrics.precision_score(targets, predictions,
                                    average='weighted')
f1 = metrics.f1_score(targets, predictions, average='weighted')
accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(targets, predictions)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so straightforward to get the metrics you mentioned (i.e., correct, incorrect, partial, missing, spurious) which I believe are the same ones as SemEval'13 challenge introduced.

I also needed to report some results based on these metrics and ended up coding it myself:

- [detailed explanation of these metrics](http://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2018/05/09/Named_Entity_Evaluation/)
- [my own code implementation](https://github.com/davidsbatista/NER-Evaluation) (it's really too much for a SO post)

I'm working together with someone else and we are planning to release that as package that can be easily integrated with open-source NER systems and/or read standard formats like CoNLL. Feel free to join and help us out :)

Comment: Actually some background to provide, I am trying to do something like this for Rasa.  In fact, I am just wrapping up now ready to make a pull request and "ended up coding it myself" as well.  I was hoping to spare myself the work, however as I am sure we both know, there are many different metrics one can choose for evaluating NER predictions.  I will look at your work when I get the time as well.